# Line graph only appears a little bit in the top and

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I try to make a line graph with python and the graph only appears a little in the end of the canvas in the GUI. The data that should be paper was taken from the database.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABxPN.png)

```
import sqlite3 ###----------------Connecting to the database-------------##### 
DB = sqlite3.connect ("personal_project.db")

CURSOR = DB.cursor()
###----------------create the SQL command to create the table and save data-------------######
 COMMAND1 = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 
          balance (
          UserID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
          Date TEXT,
          Amount TEXT,
          Descriotion)"""
CURSOR.execute(COMMAND1)

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

###----------------Create the window-------------#####
main_WINDOW = Tk()
main_WINDOW.title("Study App")
main_WINDOW.geometry("1940x1080")#width*length
main_WINDOW.configure(bg="#ffffff")   

###------Show Information Using Graph-------###
graquery = '''SELECT Date, Amount FROM balance'''
CURSOR.execute(graquery)
graresults = CURSOR.fetchall()
Date = [result[0] for result in graresults]
Amount = [result[1] for result in graresults]
figure = plt.figure()
plt.plot(Date, Amount)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Amount')
plt.title('Balance graph Graph')
gracanvas = Canvas(main_WINDOW, width=1070, height=452)
gracanvas.pack()
gracanvas.place(x=356, y=270)
figure_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, gracanvas)
gracanvas.create_window(0,0,window=figure_canvas.get_tk_widget())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
gracanvas.create_window(0,0,window=figure_canvas.get_tk_widget())
```

The `create_window` method by default centers the window at the given coordinate, which is what your image looks like. If you want the top-left corner of the window to be at 0,0, specify `anchor="nw"` so that the northwest corner of the window is at the given coordinate.

```
gracanvas.create_window(0,0,window=figure_canvas.get_tk_widget(), anchor="nw") 
#                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```